# How to drag multiple shape on canvas? [kineticjs]

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, multi-touch

For example:
one tap is moving a shape.
Another tap is moving another shape at same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have shared a small experiment I did on Kinetic + Multi Touch [here](https://github.com/atomictag/Kinetic.MultiTouch). Have a look - perhaps it can help until "real" multitouch becomes available in Kinetic

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a Kinetic Group like this:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-complex-shapes-using-groups-with-kineticjs/

Here's how to declare an empty group and make it draggable:

```
  var group = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: 220,
    y: 40,
    draggable:true
  });
```

So in the tap handler of a shape, you can add the tapped object to the group.

```
  circle.on('tap', function() {
    group.add(circle);
  });
```

Then you can drag the assembled group as necessary.

And if you need multiple groups, you can move individual shapes between the different groups like this:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-move-shape-to-another-container-with-kineticjs/

```
    circle.moveTo(someOtherGroup);
```

Comment: Theoretically, it should work. Example at second link doesn't work on ipad as expected - nothing happens at second touch.

Comment: I don't have ipad to debug link#2  :(  One thought though...if you drop back to version 4.3.3 and retry does that work?

Comment: Nope. Look like kineticjs don't have build in support for multitouch dragging.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of dragging two shapes at the same time, you will have to grab the touch event from the browser and read it as

```
touches[0] and touches[1] events
```

This is how you differentiate between separate touch events occurring simultaneously

official kineticjs example:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-multi-touch-scale-stage-with-kineticjs/